# Distribute indices evenly in multidimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I would like to create a snippet in python to distribute a range of indices evenly on a multidimensional array with repeated values such that i get this for an array with dimensions (7,13):

```
[[0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 2]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 2]]
```

This is trivial for an array with equal numbers, f.ex. N = 12, 16. But for any other cases I would like to copy a random number in that row.

Additionally, it should be generalized so that each row may have varying max numbers. Row 4 may perhaps have a max of 5, such that

```
[[0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 2]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 0]
 [0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 5]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 2]]
```

So far I have have attempted to do it like this

```
matches=[]
for pos in range(num_pos):
    matches.append([i for i in range(0, lens[pos]) for _ in range(num_opp/lens[pos])])

matches = np.asarray(matches) # Matrix of perfect matches
```

which does not account for the extra fractions of num_opp/lens[pos]), which add up to another element in each row.

Comment: Please post the code you tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
def make_index_matrix(dim, max_values):
    assert len(max_values) == dim[0]
    out = np.zeros(dim)

    for k, mv in enumerate(max_values):
        assert mv > 0
        a = np.arange(mv).repeat(np.floor(dim[1]/mv))

        if len(a) < dim[1]:
            r = np.arange(mv)
            np.random.shuffle(r)
            a = np.concatenate((a, r))

        out[k,:] = a[:dim[1]]

    return out
```

The first parameter defines the matrix dimensions, the second one should contain one value (> 0) per row giving the upper bound.

Some examples:

```
In [3]: make_index_matrix((4, 4), np.arange(1, 5))
Out[3]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 1., 2., 1.],
       [0., 1., 2., 3.]])
In [4]: make_index_matrix((4, 11), np.arange(1, 5))
Out[4]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 2., 2., 3., 3., 3., 2., 0.]]
```